# How to compile and insmod usbmouse.c?

Tags: linux, kernel, linux-kernel, drivers, usb-drive

I'm trying to develop an usb mouse driver for Linux. As far as I know, I can start with [usbmouse.c](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/drivers/hid/usbhid/usbmouse.c) and build from there. I wish to insert a few printk calls, insmod the driver, plug an usb device and see the messages with dmesg.

1. How can I compile usbmouse.c?
2. How can I insmod it, so it gets called for new devices plugged in?

Thanks!

Comment: What about patching *kernel's* usbmouse.c (in your kernel source tree) then leave kernel makefile do the job ?

Comment: @MC68020, that requires me to compile the kernel, right? (I have no experience with that) I'm looking for a way with insmod, so I can load/unload my custom driver as needed in an already configured Linux machine.

Comment: Yes ! It will require to compile the kernel. However, I believe it is the simplest way to achieve your goal (as described in OP). That way you won't have to bother with a **lot** of things kernel's make file will deal with transparently. As you can read in the usbmouse.c comments, Linus himself got some trouble with it. Not to say that I, personally, would not encompass any sort of driver project with no experience in building the linux kernel from sources. Sorry for being sincere about that. Good luck anyhow ! :-)